# saltstack: run powershell script in a state

Tags: powershell, salt-stack

I'm trying to download uru from bitbucket and try to install using vagrant with default login credentials. I'm able to download the archive. When ever I try to run the script see this error - `Invalidly-formated env parameter. See documentation.`  I'm able to run the script without any errors. I'm running this locally using vagrant in masterless mode. Any help is really appreciated.

```
download_uru:
  file.managed:
    - name: c:\uru-0.8.3-windows-x86.7z
    - source: https://bitbucket.org/jonforums/uru/downloads/uru-0.8.3-windows-x86.7z
    - source_hash: sha256=f2a7b4ed8ef6b02613b134da19a31293c7423e8fbbd8e49ec5c1c86c5f3a0815

install_uru:
  cmd.run:
    - source: salt://ruby/files/install_uru.ps1
    - shell: powershell
    - env: "-ExecutionPolicy bypass"
    - runas: "vagrant"
    - password: "vagrant"
    - require:
      - file: download_uru
```

$cat install_uru.ps1

```
set-alias sz "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"

sz x -oC: C:\uru-0.8.3-windows-x86.7z -r ;
```

c:\salt\salt-call.bat --version

salt-call 2016.11.3 (Carbon)

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/23631

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is due to the wrong format of the `-env` parameter. As described in the [official documentation](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.cmd.html#salt.states.cmd.run) it must be a **list** and you are setting a **string**.

Fix the `install_uru` state like the code below and it will run correctly.

```
install_uru:
  cmd.run:
    - source: salt://ruby/install_uru.ps1
    - shell: powershell
    - env: 
      - ExecutionPolicy: "bypass"
    - runas: "vagrant"
    - password: "vagrant"
    - require:
      - file: download_uru
```

Comment: You're welcome @user6136315. 
If the answer solved your problem please mark it as the right solution.

Comment: as of today one has to use the state function "cmd.script" instead of "cmd.run" with the parameter "source" (https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.cmd.html#salt.states.cmd.script)

Answer (score 1):

This is also working.

```
download_uru:
  file.managed:
    - name: c:\uru-0.8.3-windows-x86.7z
    - source: https://bitbucket.org/jonforums/uru/downloads/uru-0.8.3-windows-x86.7z
    - source_hash: sha256=f2a7b4ed8ef6b02613b134da19a31293c7423e8fbbd8e49ec5c1c86c5f3a0815

salt://ruby/files/install_uru.ps1:
  cmd.script:
    - shell: powershell
    - env:
      - ExecutionPolicy: "bypass"
    - cwd: C:\
```